# customize the distance between css components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using the react-d3-speedometer blibrary to generate the gauge chart below. However, I need to reduce the space between the gauge chart and the date, I have already used padding space, option mt or mb in classname but without any success.

```
<div className="col-auto mb-3" key={esp.id}>
 <div className="card">
  <h5 className="card-header">X</h5>
   <ReactSpeedometer 
    id={"gauge-chart-" + esp.id}
    fluidWidth={true}
    minValue={0}
    maxValue={40}
    value={32}
    valueFormat={'d'}
    customSegmentStops={[0, 10, 20, 30, 40]}
    segmentColors={['#a3be8c','#ebcb8b', '#d08770', '#bf616a']}
    labelFontSize={'10px'}
    valueTextFontSize={'28px'}
    valueTextFontWeight={'500'}
    paddingHorizontal={17}
    paddingVertical={17}
    currentValueText="#{value}˚C"
    currentValuePlaceholderStyle={"#{value}"}
    textColor={textColor}
    />
    <p className="prog_temp text-secondary mt-1">30/10/2020 10:43:44</p>
    <p className="prog_temp text-info mt-1">Temperature: 33˚C</p>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm btn-block">Temperature Ajust</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm btn-block">Status Ajust</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'am CSS file

```
.prog_temp {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

What other way could you use to decrease this space with CSS?

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10sMU0zaWoYK7AA3n46PUMOSpfnjUtNtx/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

That space is first created because of the

tags and second because of the font itself. Try using line-height after you have set the margin and padding to 0 and decreased or increased the font-size.

```
p
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-size:60px;
  line-height:30px;
}
```